# What is some good introduction to lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, textbook-recommendation, lo.logic

I have some background in set theory and automata and I am looking for a good place to start with lambda calculus.

Comment: I suspect it'd help to distinguish typed and untyped lambda calculus, since they're quite different subjects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is, of course, the very famous book by Barendregt,

- The Lambda Calculus, Its Syntax and Semantics (Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics, Volume 103). Revised Edition, North-Holland, 1985. [(link to vendor)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444875085)

which doesn't require much background except for the usual mathematical maturity. This is mostly about the *untyped* lambda calculus. He also has some introductory notes [here](ftp://ftp.cs.ru.nl/pub/CompMath.Found/lambda.pdf).

Comment: Link to the notes is broken - would it be possible to update it.

Comment: @Mika'il The link to the notes works absolutely fine for me.

Comment: The link to book now returns 404 not found.

Answer (score 4):

An introductory book that seems very nice to me is [*Lambda-Calculus and Combinators. An introduction*](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1175709) by J. Roger Hindley and Jonathan P. Seldin.

Comment: Plus it has exercises and some of them have solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The best books that I've found are:

- Very basic: Hankin, An introduction to the lambda calculus for computer scientists.
- Advanced: Sorensen and Urzyczyn, Lectures on the Curry-Howard isomorphism.
- Advanced: Hindley, Basic simple type theory.
- The Bible: Barendregt, The lambda calculus: its syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 4):

Another excellent book is "Lambda-calculus, types and models" Ellis Horwood (1993) by Jean-Louis Krivine http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~krivine/articles/Lambda.pdf

Comment: The link in this answer no longer works but the same text can be found here: https://www.irif.fr/~krivine/articles/Lambda.pdf - and in [some other places](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Krivine+Lambda+calculus+types+models).

Answer (score 2):

I really enjoy *[Types and Programming Languages](http://books.google.com/books?id=ti6zoAC9Ph8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Benjamin C. Pierce. We used this for a course on the lambda calculus, and I felt this was a great way for a mathematician to learn the subject

Answer (score 1):

Stoy's book:

Joseph E. Stoy, Denotational Semantics: The Scott-Strachey Approach to Programming Language Semantics. MIT Press, Cambridge, Massachusetts, 1977

Is a classic, and highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

[Proof and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/Proofs+Types.html) is a good place to learn about the Curry-Howard isomorphism.